# File not found - http://localhost/path-file-script-or-image

Tags: node.js, localhost, apache2

When I visit my node application running on my raspberry pi at 10.0.my.ip.address the app loads but get 404 multiple files not found. The src to my files, scripts and images look similar to this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/Ziroid_Functions/Clovis_App/public/clovisapp.css">

<img src="http://localhost/Ziroid_Functions/Clovis_App/public/img/doubleUp.png" alt="Smiley face" >

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/Ziroid_Functions/Clovis_App/public/js/radar.js"></script>
```

Whats weird is that these lines on code worked yesterday. I added a few more src links which got errors. I restarted my apache server on desktop top then all the sudden my desktop started getting errors with all src links being localhost/some-address.

I tried loading application on my other computer and all the scirpts,images and links load fine.

What might the problem be and how do I fix this?

Comment: I posted another question last week that was similar. Src tags with localhost would not load on my phone. We concluded that was the case becasue phone didnt support web servers. Now localhost src would work on my main desktop. The link to that question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54245195/why-src-attruibute-wont-render-files-at-localhost

Comment: Now that I experimented with it further, believe I took wrong approach. Just noticing that, the computers that render localhost all have a version of the program on their localhost. Hints why its working on those computers. Originally I thought the localhost would only render version running on my raspberry Pi. So using localhost wont work. Using the IP address instead of localhost will work but then Ill have to update the src with the new IP address every time I switch networks. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I resolved this issue simply by removing localhost from src and using express static files to render files from my public folder